# Overriding a log4j.properties file

Tags: log4j

I am trying to make log4j work in a project that uses a software framework that also uses log4j. The framework uses a log4j.properties file, so does that mean that I also have to use a properties file? I prefer the xml format. Let me know if that should create problems, it is not working as of now with my xml config file and I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to replace the log4j.properties file with your own log4j.xml file. However, you probably want to make sure that the loggers/appenders etc that were in the original properties file also exist in your new log4j.xml file (or you may start missing log events).

If your log4j.xml is currently not working (what exactly are you seeing, btw), check that your classpath does not contain another log4j.properties or log4j.xml file (perhaps inside a jar?) If another log4j.properties exists, even in the final element of the classpath, it will still be loaded before a log4j.xml file in the beginning of the classpath.

Furthermore, you can enable log4j internal debugging with system property `-Dlog4j.configDebug=true`. This may give you a clue on what the problem is with the log4j.xml file.